# MySQL NULL or usser input

Tags: php, mysql, database, input

This code is for inserting data in to my tables.

```
     $sku = $conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['sku']);
    $name = $conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['name']);
    $price =  $conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['price']);
    $type =  $conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['type']);
    $size =  $conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['size']);
    $bWeight =  $conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['bWeight']);
    $fHeight =  $conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['fHeight']);
    $fWeight =  $conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['fWeight']);
    $fLenght =  $conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['fLenght']);


    //Insert Into mainInfo
    $sql = "INSERT INTO mainInfo (sku, name, price, type) VALUES ('$sku', 
    '$name', '$price', '$type')";
    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
      echo "Records inserted Successfully <br> ";
    } else {
      echo "Error couldnt insert records: " .$conn->error;
    }


    //Insert Into properties
    $sql = "INSERT INTO properties (size, bWeight, fHeight, fWeight, fLenght, 
    sku) VALUES ('$size', '$bWeight', '$fHeight', '$fWeight', '$fLenght', 
    '$sku')";
    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
      echo "Records inserted Successfully <br> ";
    } else {
      echo "Error couldnt insert records: " .$conn->error;
    }
```

Here is the HTML code, if that is neccesary.

```
     <form class="prodInf" method="post" action="pehape/apstrade.php" >

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label class="labelName" for="prodSKU"><b>SKU</b> </label>
        <input type="text" name="sku">
          <br>
        <label class ="labelName"for="prodName"><b>Name</b> </label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
          <br>
        <label class ="labelName"for="prodPrice"><b>Price</b> </label>
        <input type="text" name="price">
          <br>
        <label id="lastProdInf" class ="labelName"for="prodType">Type 
      Switcher</label>
        <select class="prodctType" name="type">
          <option value="1" selected="selected">DVD-Disc</option>
          <option value="2">Book</option>
          <option value="3">Furniture</option>
        </select>

     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

  <br>

  <!--type apraksts un ievade -->
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="inputDisplay">

        <!--DvD logs -->
        <div class="inputDvd">

            <label class="typePar" for="size"><b>Size</b> </label>
            <input type="text" name="size">

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed 
     gravida fringilla sem, at lobortis lorem pulvinar et.</p>
        </div>

        <!--book logs -->
        <div class="inputBook">

            <label class="typePar" for="bWeight"><b>Weight</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="bWeight">

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed 
     gravida fringilla sem, at lobortis lorem pulvinar et.</p>
        </div>

        <!--furniture logs -->
        <div class="inputFurniture">

            <label class="typePar" for="fHeight"><b>Height</b> </label>
            <input type="text" name="fHeight">
              <br>
            <label class="typePar" for="fWeight"><b>Weight</b> </label>
            <input type="text" name="fWeight">
              <br>
            <label class="typePar" for="fLenght"><b>Lenght</b></label>
             <input type="text" name="fLenght">

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed 
    gravida fringilla sem, at lobortis lorem pulvinar et.</p>
        </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" name="save" value="submit">
</form>
```

If user doesn't input data in some of the fields, how can i leave them empty, right now this code gives me.
Error couldnt insert records: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'bWeight' at row 1
after i input data only in $size

Comment: @CROZET is correct and also besides those two checking , please ensure the field names of your table whether they match with the names you have used in your query or not .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, ensure that null values are allowed in your database schema.
Then, you should not use [`real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for integers because this function always returns a string (see the doc).

You can use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/function.filter-var.php) to ensure the provided value is an integer or force a cast to int with `$value = (int) $userInput`.

Also note that it is better to use prepared statements everywhere instead of `real_escape_string`

Comment: @user3783243 `"00123"` is not an integer : it is a string. If you get a different value after a cast from a string to an int, it means that your original data was not an integer. And if you have to keep leading zeros (for zip codes for example) you should not store it as an integer but as a string. It is a bad practice to rely on mysql for casting string to int : if you expect an int into your table, send an int not something else while hoping mysql will convert correctly to an int.

Comment: you're right for your example of weights without the unit, this value is meaningless but the value with units is not an integer and should not be stored as an int.

Comment: (simplifying previous comments) There is nothing in the manual about `real_escape_string` not being used on integers. Since the value is quoted in the query it should be escaped. Casting is likely to lose data.